# valgrind - total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated

Tags: valgrind

I run valgrind on binary always show as bellow even I have allocated memory using malloc.

```
==13775== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13775==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13775==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==13775== 
==13775== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible

Please let me know solution if some faced this problem previously.
```

Comment: Please post complete example of minimal program in question, its compilation and linking commands, and `ldd` output on that binary.

Comment: Any minimal ( malloc(4) and free ) is not working. Compiler using : x86_64-wrs-linux-g++ -m64 LDD: bash-4.2# ldd ./mydaemonprocess 
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffcffff000)
 libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x0000003713e00000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003712e00000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003712600000)
 librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003714200000)
 libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x0000003713600000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003715200000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6

Comment: I don't see `libc` in your `ldd` output. `malloc` is implemented there, which is why valgrind cannot replace it with its trap functions.

Comment: Then is any alternative way to check memleak. I use cat /proc/<pid>/maps and heap is not growing. Please tell me the solution

Comment: More over its daemon process, I am exiting parent and make child as daemon. in child code I am doing 4 bytes and assigning fd to pointer.

Comment: Easiest way is to link with dynamic libc instead of static one. What system is it? Check your linking line for `static` and probably make symlink `/usr/lib/libc.so` pointing to `libc.so.6` of your system (usually somewhere in `/lib`).

Comment: Its good information you provided. Do yave any idea about child and parent relation. So I will explain my scenario is like this. I will create the fork and if pid is greater than zero(0) I will exit the parent. After that I will continue and make the process as daemon and return to main and from main I will call function and there I will use malloc. So valgrind has to show usage of heap of both parent and child right? but its showing only parent.

Comment: Try `valgrind --trace-children=yes ./your_program`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, valgrind not seeing any malloc/free calls is due to one of the
following reasons:

1 the program is linked statically

2 the program is linked dynamically, but malloc/free library is static

3 malloc/free lib is dynamic, but it is a 'non standard' library (for example tcmalloc)

As ldd shows that you have some dynamic libraries, it is not reason 1.
So, it might be reason 2 or reason 3.
For both 2 and 3, you can make it work by using the option
   --soname-synonyms=somalloc=....

See user manual for more details

Comment: Its good information you provided. Do yave any idea about child and parent relation. So I will explain my scenario is like this. I will create the fork and if pid is greater than zero(0) I will exit the parent. After that I will continue and make the process as daemon and return to main and from main I will call function and there I will use malloc. So valgrind has to show usage of heap of both parent and child right? but its showing only parent.